# Change primary key value of an object store

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

How can I change the primary key value (`keyPath`) of an object store? If this is not possible, does IndexedDB team have any plans to support this feature?

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify the key path of an object store (or index). Doing so would require re-inserting all data into the store which could fail (e.g. if there are constraint failures), so it's left to user code to do that as part of an upgrade (version change).

Indexed DB v2 (support coming soon in Firefox and Chrome, at least) allows you to rename stores (and indexes) during schema changes, so you can do a version upgrade which creates a new store, copies the data over, responds to constraint failures appropriately, deletes the old store, then renames the new one. Until "v2" support is widespread you're stuck with keeping the new name, though.

Comment: Josh, do you happen to have a link tracking version 2 progress you can share?

Comment: Best I've got is in the spec itself: https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/ - there are comments which read "...new in this edition..." and give what version support for v2 features will appear in for FF/Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it.